# Is it necessary to free memory resources before you program terminates?

Tags: c++, software-design

It seems pretty standard practice to free program resources before the main process finishes executing. But as I'm learning OpenGL/Vulkan, I've found one of the things that seems kind of unnecessary in the tutorials is the amount of code dedicated to resource cleanup. Is there any tangible benefit to cleaning up your own resources the moment before your program exits? Don't modern operating systems do that already when a process finishes?

This is not a GL / Vulkan question, it's more general and applies to any language where the developer manages their own memory.

Comment: Note that tutorials often omit boilerplate code like error checking and resource cleanup, so don't just blindly follow their example.

Comment: Imagine a text-editor app. At each character the user writes, something is allocated on the heap for temporary use. How many characters will the user be able to write before he gets out of RAM? He will need to close the app to free the RAM. A bit annoying :)

Comment: I would recommend writing code that cleans up resources. If you wish to speed up quitting your application you can bypass all destructors by simply calling `exit(0)`. There are a number of games that do this but many more that don't.

Answer (score 4):

Part of writing good code is writing code that can be used for other purposes and that forms a collection of useful tools. If your code doesn't clean up after itself when it's finished, then it's much harder to use it as a part of something else. It's also much harder to find memory leaks in code that doesn't clean up after itself.

Of course, if your project is a one-off and there's no particular educational purpose in learning how to shut it down cleanly, then that can probably be omitted.

Comment: The experience has taken shape. +1 I like reading your answers/comments sir.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the resource, what "cleanup" means, what you are actually doing and other things. Here are few points worth considering:

1. "what am I doing?" Say you write a modular code. Then you want to have all those destructors. After all someone may want to use your code in a different context, where the process doesn't shutdown once you finished dealing with the code.
2. "resource and cleanup" Memory is indeed automatically reclaimed by most modern operating systems (but is it guaranteed that every OS ever will do that?). But what if you are actually doing some networking? What if you want to send a "bye bye" message to your server in order to gather statistics? Perhaps you want that cleanup. And it is easier to write it from the start, rather then adding it later.
3. "OS independent code" Do you really want to write OS dependent code? Is it really a standard that the OS always reclaims any resource?
4. "bugs, bugs, bugs" Operating systems do have bugs. And lots of them. Whether it is your responsibility to write the code in a bullet-proof fashion is of course debatable. Still something worth considering.